# How to customize select outline of React AG-Grid cell?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In AG-Grid, by default, selecting a cell by clicking on it gives a blue outline:

[image]

However, I have added a border to all my cells by modifying the `cellStyle` property for `defaultColDef`:

```
cellStyle: (params) => {
    return {
        border: '1px solid #cccaca',
    }
},
```

The cells end up looking like this, but clicking on them does not show a blue outline (I'm guessing it is hidden by the borders):

[image]

Is there a way to customize cells to have both a border and a selection outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this class

```
.ag-cell-focus {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

By doing so, your focused cell will be red bordered.

Playground: https://plnkr.co/edit/jicOlLIWOldJPMhD?preview (Look for age column)

**UPDATE**

To clear borders when clicked outside

```
.ag-has-focus .ag-cell-focus {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! Also wondering - is there a clean way to enable 'deselecting/unfocusing' of cells with a customized focus border? If I click outside the grid, the red border stays.

Comment: Answered your question